# arduino bluetooth text receiving not working well

Tags: arduino, bluetooth

I am trying to make a lighting system using an RGB Led strip controlled by my phone via Bluetooth. I am using an Arduino nano and HC-06 for the Bluetooth, like this:

[image]

And this is my code:

```cpp
#include "FastLED.h"
#define NUM_LEDS 10
#define LED_PIN 10
#define COLOR_ORDER GRB
CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];

SoftwareSerial Bluetooth(3, 2); // Arduino(RX, TX) - Bluetooth (TX, RX)

// LED color 
int R, G, B;

int brightness = 100; // Initial brightness

String dataIn = "";

void setup() {
  delay( 3000 );//power-up safety delay
  FastLED.addLeds<WS2812B, LED_PIN, COLOR_ORDER>(leds, NUM_LEDS).setCorrection(TypicalLEDStrip);
  FastLED.setBrightness(brightness);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Bluetooth.begin(9600);//9600  115200

}

void loop() {
  if (Bluetooth.available() > 0) {    
    dataIn = Bluetooth.readString(); 
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println(dataIn);
    if (dataIn.startsWith("1")) {
      String stringR = dataIn.substring(dataIn.indexOf("R") + 1);
      R = stringR.toInt();
      String stringG = dataIn.substring(dataIn.indexOf("G") + 1);
      G = stringG.toInt();
      String stringB = dataIn.substring(dataIn.indexOf("B") + 1);
      B = stringB.toInt();
      String Stringb = dataIn.substring(dataIn.indexOf("b") + 1);
      brightness = Stringb.toInt();
    
      Serial.println(stringR + "   " + R);
      Serial.println(stringG + "   " + G);
      Serial.println(stringB + "   " + B);
      }
   }
}
```

The text I'm sending the Arduino is:

*1R(red value)G(green value)B(blue value)b(brightness value)*

eg. *1R75G75B100b50*

When I send some text to the Arduino with an app in the google play store, the received string is (not always but mostly) distorted. (like [⸮ or H⸮ or ⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮ and so forth)

I have tried changing the delay, using different apps, and using different Bluetooth modules but it did not work.

Can I get some help?

Comment: Please include some kind of repository link or a Tinkercad project link.

Comment: what do you mean?